# Supposed low temperature of calcium carbide synthesis

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reference-request

I came across an interesting reaction on [allreactions.com under silicon tab](http://allreactions.com/index.php/group-4a/silicon):

$$\ce{SiO2 + 5 C(coke) + CaO ->[\pu{800–1000 °C}] Si + CaC2 + 3 CO}$$

Unfortunately the website doesn't provide sources and I wanted to read further about this reaction, particularly about the reaction time. If anyone here could point me to another source I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 4):

Liu et al. in 2012 [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/ie300671w)] showed experimental data that lead me to believe this to be inaccurate. Two relevant informations from their findings:

> $\ce{SiO2}$ and $\ce{Al2O3}$ do not react with coke at temperatures lower than $\pu{1460 °C}$, but they do react with $\ce{CaO}$ to form $\ce{Ca3SiO5}$ and $\ce{Ca2Al2O5}$, respectively […]
>
> Note that the behaviors of $\ce{SiO2}$ and $\ce{Al2O3}$ observed in this work do not agree with some literature, which reported that both $\ce{SiO2}$ and  $\ce{Al2O3}$ reacted with coke at temperatures of $\pu{∼ 1200 °C}$.

Also, in *Fundamentals of Metallurgical Processes: International Series on Materials Science and Technology* [[2, p. 174](https://doi.org/10.1016/C2013-0-03773-5)] it is written that calcium carbide is not stable in the presence of silicon and undergoes the reaction:

> $$\ce{2 SiO2 + 2 C + CaC2 <=> Ca + 2 Si + 4 CO}$$

#### References

1. Li, G.; Liu, Q.; Liu, Z. $\ce{CaC2}$ Production from Pulverized Coke and $\ce{CaO}$ at Low Temperatures—Reaction Mechanisms. *Ind. Eng. Chem. Res.* **2012**, 51 (33), 10742–10747. DOI: [10.1021/ie300671w](https://doi.org/10.1021/ie300671w).
2. Coudurier, L.; Hopkins, D. W.; Wilkomirsky, I. *Fundamentals of Metallurgical Processes*, 2nd ed.; Hopkins, D. W., Ed.; International series on materials science and technology; Pergamon Press: Oxford [Oxfordshire]; New York, **1985**; Vol. 27. ISBN: 978-0-08-032536-1, eBook ISBN: 9781483162409, DOI: [10.1016/C2013-0-03773-5](https://doi.org/10.1016/C2013-0-03773-5).

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne (cc Nilay Ghosh) Please note that using `mhchem` for denoting references like `$\ce{^{[1]}}$` is just evil. Square brackets are used in Markdown markup, hence you might want to escape them with `\[` or `\]`, but not by abusing MathJax. Also, keep in mind commonly used Latin words and abbreviations are never italicized, and we prefer to use ACS citation style (or, a least, keep your style consistent).

Comment: @andselisk: I agree with you, specifically with ~\ce{[]}$` to show the references. But I didn't have a choice because Nilay already have done that for first reference. I was just afraid I'd ruin the formulation and go with the his method. I have seen suire bracker with references with other experience bloggers. Sorry.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne No need to apologize, this is just a reminder/suggestion, not an accusation (sorry if my comment sounds so). Figuring out a mishmash of edits isn't an easy job, so thank you for participating in posts improvement!

Comment: @andselisk: I have a suggestion if you can go with it. When I'm editiong I can't see how I'm doing because edited version is not visual until I submit it. Can you do something to visualize the text while doing editing. That would be really helpful. Thanks for encouragement. ;-)

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Hmm, probably a side-by-side view would be more useful for you; there are some solutions mentioned in [Editor to use on PC with windows to format answers?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4029/editor-to-use-on-pc-with-windows-to-format-answers), such as using [SOX](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) or [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/). I have an ancient square monitor with plenty of vertical space, so I just scroll back-and-forth a little when I want to check what my scribble renders to.